# url re writing using htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on property site and I want to rewrite some of the url in my site. There are some urls which list the property type-wise. In the footer there is a list of property types such as hotels, privatevilla, apartments....etc.

Now the url of this page is `property_list.php?propertytype_id=12` where `12` is the property `id` of apartment. Instead of this url I'd given apartments.

When user clicks on this link then the url should be `sitename/apartments` instead of showing `property_list.php?propertytype_id=12`. I've written the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)?$ /property_list.php?propertytype_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

When I click on aprtments then at that time it is showing apartments in the url and listing all apartments but the thing is it is redirecting home page and other pages also.

How do I redirect only property type related pages?

Comment: You can try http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test your htaccess

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want this?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^apartments$ /property_list.php?propertytype_id=12 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for. So when the URL is `/sitename/apartments` rewrite it to `/property_list.php?propertytype_id=12`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sitename/apartments [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /property_list.php?propertytype_id=12 [NC,L]
```